# Visualize 2D data in a completely filled square 2D grid, along two ordered axes

Tags: visualization

For visualization purposes, I would like to show an array with 2D data in a completely filled (near) square 2D grid, along two ordered axes.

If the array has 10,000 items and each item consists of two values `a` and `b`, these items should be placed in a 100x100 grid in such a way that:

- The item with the **smallest** `a` and **smallest** `b` value is placed in cell `[0, 0]`
- The item with the **smallest** `a` and **highest** `b` value is placed in cell `[0, 100]`
- The item with the **highest** `a` and **smallest** `b` value is placed in cell `[100, 0]`
- The item with the **highest** `a` and **highest** `b` value is placed in cell `[100, 100]`

The other cells should be filled to preserve as much of the data's ordering as possible.

Are there any algorithms that can create such a grid? Or are there other solutions for this problem, that might be better suited to visualize such data?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone is going to post a single line solution for this but until then, here is my answer. I don't know what is the type of the object you have in the first place but let's say you have a 5X5 Pandas DataFrame, where elements are arrays like the this:

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4   col_5
0   (4, 4)  (1, 4)  (4, 3)  (2, 4)  (4, 5)
1   (3, 4)  (1, 2)  (4, 1)  (3, 1)  (4, 2)
2   (1, 5)  (1, 1)  (1, 3)  (2, 3)  (3, 3)
3   (5, 1)  (3, 2)  (2, 5)  (3, 5)  (5, 4)
4   (5, 2)  (5, 5)  (2, 2)  (2, 1)  (5, 3)
```

Convert the values to a list first:

```
list_ = df.values.tolist()
```

Flatten and wrap the result

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in list_ for item in sublist]
wrapped_list = [flat_list]
```

Then run the following sorting for the entries in whatever order you prefer:

```
for elm in wrapped_list:                                                              
    elm.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    elm.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Unwrap the result and convert back to a DataFrame:

```
final_pd = pd.DataFrame()
i=0
while i < 25:
  final_pd[f"col_{i//5}"] = wrapped_list[i:i+5]
  i += 5
```

Result:

```
    col_0   col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4
0   (1, 1)  (1, 2)  (1, 3)  (1, 4)  (1, 5)
1   (2, 1)  (2, 2)  (2, 3)  (2, 4)  (2, 5)
2   (3, 1)  (3, 2)  (3, 3)  (3, 4)  (3, 5)
3   (4, 1)  (4, 2)  (4, 3)  (4, 4)  (4, 5)
4   (5, 1)  (5, 2)  (5, 3)  (5, 4)  (5, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html), [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) and [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html).

For an array

```
SeedRandom[321];
array = RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 9}], {6, 4, 2}];
Grid[array
 , Frame -> All
 , FrameStyle -> LightGray
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then `Flatten` one level to the pairs, `Sort`, and `Partition` by the second [`Dimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html) to return to original dimensions.

```
Grid[
 Partition[Sort@Flatten[array, 1], Dimensions[array][[2]]]
 , Frame -> All
 , FrameStyle -> LightGray
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`Sort` works on many types so the same code can be used for data of mixed type pairs. For example, complex numbers and text.

```
SeedRandom[123];
mixedarray =
  Partition[
   Thread[{
     Complex @@@ RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 5}], {24, 2}]
     , RandomSample[WordList[], 24]
     }]
   , 4];
Grid[mixedarray
 , Frame -> All
 , FrameStyle -> LightGray
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then same code as above

```
Grid[
 Partition[Sort@Flatten[mixedarray, 1], Dimensions[mixedarray][[2]]]
 , Frame -> All
 , FrameStyle -> LightGray
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.